# Tabindex on text input immediately after WordPress title input

Tags: custom-field, post-editor

The following code adds a text input for a subtitle to the space directly below the title input, via the `edit_form_after_title` hook. However, when editing the title, pressing tab moves the cursor to the main post editor and I can't figure out what tabindex I should use (or some other method if available) in order to tab from the title to my subtitle input instead.

```
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'add_input' );

function add_input(){

    global $post;

    $options = get_option( 'kia_subtitle_options' );

    // only show input if the post type was not enabled in options
    if ( isset ( $options['post_types'] ) && in_array( $post->post_type, $options[ 'post_types'] ) ) {

        //create the meta field (don't use a metabox, we have our own styling):
        wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'kia_subnonce' );

        //get the subtitle value (if set)
        $sub = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'kia_subtitle', true );

        // echo the inputfield with the value.
        printf( '<input type="text" class="widefat" name="subtitle" placeholder="%s" value="%s" id="the_subtitle" tabindex="1"/>',
                __( 'Subtitle', 'kia-subtitle'   ),
                 esc_attr($sub) );
     }
}
```

Comment: The focus is controlled by a `blur` event, if I remember that correctly. You could try to replace this event with your own.

Comment: @toscho do you have any idea what script that might be in, so I could take a look?

Comment: The answers below are cool, but they appear to require that you write a script that explicitly calls out every existing field, which is tricky if you need add a ton of fields, or are not sure if fields will be added in the future to the `edit_form_after_title` area. Has anyone figured out a way to just disable whatever jquery shenanigans are going on and just have the browser follow the natural tab order of the elements as the appear in the HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found last part of @birgire answer the most useful way, however it breaks the possibility to *tab* to content. In fact I think is normal focus the content by click tab while in the subtitle field.

To do that, you have also to take care if the content is shown in the "Text" tab or in the "Visual" tab (TynyMCE).

I put the code inline , inside your function, but you can use `wp_enqueue_script` or add it to some javascript file already enqueued in post edit screen.

```
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'add_input' );

function add_input(){
  global $post;
  $options = get_option( 'kia_subtitle_options' );
  // only show input if the post type was not enabled in options
  if ( isset ( $options['post_types'] ) && in_array( $post->post_type, $options[ 'post_types'] ) ) {
    //create the meta field (don't use a metabox, we have our own styling):
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'kia_subnonce' );
    //get the subtitle value (if set)
    $sub = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'kia_subtitle', true );
    // echo the inputfield with the value.
    printf(
      '<input type="text" class="widefat" name="subtitle" placeholder="%s" value="%s" id="the_subtitle" tabindex="1"/>',
      __( 'Subtitle', 'kia-subtitle'   ), esc_attr($sub)
     );
  ?>

  <script>
  (function($) { $(document).on( 'keydown', '#title, #the_subtitle', function( e ) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if ( 9 == keyCode){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr('id') == 'title' ? '#the_subtitle' : 'textarea#content';
    if ( (target === '#the_subtitle') || $('#wp-content-wrap').hasClass('html-active') ) {
      $(target).focus();
    } else {
      tinymce.execCommand('mceFocus',false,'content');
    }
  }
  }); })(jQuery);
  </script>

<?php
} // endif
} // end function
```

Comment: Same as I said to Birgire, not ignoring you guys and appreciate your answers. I will test them out when I get to the next continent.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be doing exactly what I need and will be updating my subtitle plugin with your script.. with a little hat-tip in the source code, of course.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try playing with the `focusout` Javascript *event* and the `focus()` method:

Here is a demo **Subtitle** plugin: `/wp-content/plugins/subtitle/subtitle.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Subtitle
 */

function custom_add_input()
{
   // your function code above ...
}

add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'custom_add_input' );

function subtitle_script( $hook )
{
        if( in_array( $hook, array( 'edit.php', 'post.php', 'post-new.php' ) ) )
        {
                wp_enqueue_script( 'subtitle-script', 
                                   plugins_url( 'js/script.js' , __FILE__ ), 
                                   array(), 
                                   '1.0.1', 
                                    FALSE 
                                 );
        }
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'subtitle_script' );
```

and here is for example a *non-jQuery* version for your `wp-content/plugins/subtitle/js/script.js` file:

```
// script.js

window.onload = function(){
    // Add event listener to the title input
    document.getElementById('title').addEventListener( 'focusout', focus_on_subtitle, false);

}

function focus_on_subtitle()
{
    document.getElementById( 'the_subtitle' ).focus();
}
```

My initial *jQuery* version didn't work, so that's why I tested the *non-jQuery* version and that works on my install ;-)

Well, this *jQuery* version seems to work:

```
jQuery(window).load( function() {
        jQuery('#title').focusout( function() {
                jQuery('#the_subtitle').focus();
        });
});
```

and this

```
jQuery(document).ready( function( ){
            jQuery('#title').focusout( function() {
                    jQuery('#the_subtitle').focus();
            });
    });
```

When the *title* input text field looses the focus:

[image: after pressing the TAB key]

it goes to the *subtitle* input text field.

But maybe it's more *user-friendly* to only intercept the `TAB` keycode in the title input text field. With a modification of [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1314479/2078474), we can for example use:

```
jQuery(document).on( 'keydown', '#title', function( event ) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if ( 9 == keyCode){
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#the_subtitle').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Just a heads up that I am doing a lot of travelling in the next 2 days. I will test this as soon as I can.

Comment: This is an excellent explanation! But it does kill the ability to tab to the content editor, so I had to give the bounty to G.M. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I made some additions to the final suggestion by @birgire to make this work without knowing the ID of the first field in the after_title area if you're using ACF. If you're not using ACF, just adjust `#acf_after_title-sortables .inside > div:first-child` to match your `after_title` area selectors.

```
// Admin Functions
( function( $ ) {
    // better accessiblity and data entry for ACF
    $(document).ready( function() {
        // if there is a an "after_title" field group
        if ( $( '#acf_after_title-sortables' ).length ) {
            // listen for keydown inside the main title field for any add/edit screen
            $('body.post-new-php, body.post-php').on( 'keydown', '#title', function( e ) {
                var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
                // if the key is tab
                if ( 9 == keyCode ) {
                    // don't do the normal core WP behavior
                    e.preventDefault();
                    // find the first field in the after_title area
                    $( '#acf_after_title-sortables .inside > div:first-child' )
                        .find( ':input:not([type=hidden])' )
                        .focus();
                }
            } );
        }
    } );
} )( jQuery );

/*
Thanks to these Stack Overflow answers for inspiration:
@neiker - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17150138/947370
@gdoron-is-supporting-monica https://stackoverflow.com/a/11278006/947370
@birgire https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/127042/41488
*/
```

( I also posted it here: https://gist.github.com/petertwise/8ebb6a76f018494fcc62171d622cc85f )